# Placing a search bar on an item list layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

I have a `ListView` which I am populating using adapter arrays. I would like to add a search bar there, but whenever I add a search bar it repeats it, so I ended up making 2 layout files: one for the search-bar and the other one for the item-list.

**ListView in my Android:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@color/bckground"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder" /> <!-- ree image-->


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            tools:text="name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/surname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"    
            tools:text="surname" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**ListView layout print-screen:**

[image]

**Search-bar file layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchtext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="Search.." />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sumbit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Search-bar layout print-screen:**

[image]

I would like to have the search-bar and item list in one layout. 
How can I combine these two layout files together?

Answer (score 0):

Add your listview in layout file which contains search bar.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchtext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="Search.." />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sumbit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search" />

    <!--Add your list view here-->
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to have the search-bar and item list in one layout. How can I combine these two layout files together?

You can't. These are conceptually two different layouts. One describes each item in the list, which is provided by the `ListView` adapter, and the other describes the top level view that contains the `ListView` and any other views that you want as part of that layout.